# creating a dependent html dropdown list using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dependent drop down list where if option one is selected it only shows `div class option1` and if option 2 is selcted it shows `div class option2`, Im not that good at JavaScript, (not jQuery) Im seeking some assistance please

```
    <select id="lstFruits" >
    <option value="1">Mango</option>
    <option value="2">Apple</option>
</select>

<div class ="option1">
<br/><br/>
Colour1 <input type="text"/>
<br/>
Taste1 <input type="text"/>
<br/>
weight1 <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="option2">
<br/><br/>
Colour2 <input type="text"/>
<br/>
Taste2 <input type="text"/>
<br/>
weight2 <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```js
// Let the DOM load before addressing elements:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var fruits = document.querySelector('#lstFruits'),
        divs = [document.querySelector('.option1'),
                document.querySelector('.option2')];

    function showMatchingOptions() {
        // Show and hide the correct div, based on the selected value
        divs[+this.value-1].style.display = '';
        divs[2-this.value].style.display = 'none';
    }
                
    // Execute the above function on every change in the select list
    fruits.addEventListener('change', showMatchingOptions);
    
    // Execute the above function also on page load, so we 
    // start with a consistent situation.
    showMatchingOptions.call(fruits);
});
```

```html
<select id="lstFruits" >
    <option value="1">Mango</option>
    <option value="2">Apple</option>
</select>

<div class ="option1">
    <br/><br/>
    Colour1 <input type="text"/>
    <br/>
    Taste1 <input type="text"/>
    <br/>
    weight1 <input type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="option2">
    <br/><br/>
    Colour2 <input type="text"/>
    <br/>
    Taste2 <input type="text"/>
    <br/>
    weight2 <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

#### More than 2 elements:

If you have more than 2 elements, you would use a `for` loop:

```
var fruits = document.querySelector('#lstFruits'),
    divs = [document.querySelector('.option1'),
            document.querySelector('.option2'),
            document.querySelector('.option3')];

function showMatchingOptions() {
    // Show and hide the correct div, based on the selected value
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = +this.value-1 === i ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: what if  i wanted to add a 3rd option to the function
`function showMatchingOptions() {
        // Show and hide the correct div, based on the selected value
        divs[+this.value-1].style.display = '';
        divs[2-this.value].style.display = 'none';
      }`

Comment: Then you would turn that into a `for` loop. I added some example code to my answer.

Comment: I am so grateful extremely, thanks again for truly assisting

Answer (score 0):

i hope! it would be helpful for u :)

http://www.bitrepository.com/dynamic-dependant-dropdown-list-us-states-counties.html